# VSCode Synchronize Error With Output Content in the file is not valid

Tags: visual-studio-code, synchronization

This is the first time for me to sync the VSCode using the GitHub account. But I experienced an error such as these when I try to sync (after login):

```
[2022-03-07 17:01:16.719] [settingssync] [info] Using settings sync service https://vscode-sync.trafficmanager.net/
[2022-03-07 17:01:16.719] [settingssync] [info] Auto Sync is disabled.
[2022-03-07 17:04:41.983] [settingssync] [info] Did reset the local sync state.
[2022-03-07 17:04:43.688] [settingssync] [error] LocalInvalidContent (UserDataSyncError) syncResource:keybindings operationId:unknown: Unable to sync keybindings because the content in the file is not valid. Please open the file and correct it.
    at y.generateSyncPreview (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:91833)
    at async y.doGenerateSyncResourcePreview (vscode-file://vscode-app/Applications/Visual%20Studio%20Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/code/electron-browser/sharedProcess/sharedProcessMain.js:76:56502)
[2022-03-07 17:04:43.693] [settingssync] [info] Settings: Stopped synchronizing settings.
[2022-03-07 17:04:43.697] [settingssync] [info] Did reset the local sync state.
```

Do you have any idea for me what to do? Because the explanation is unclear. I have tried to click while holding CMD on the path and create a new file but it is not working. Thank you

Comment: Maybe you've missed a `,` after a line. Basically, check whether your `settings.json` file has valid `JSON` in it.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, was a missed `]` in `~/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json`. I was noticed all the json files in this folder must be reviewed to be correct jsons.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You must have some syntactial error in your settings.json file. If dont find any error or dont understand JSON file, please go to https://jsonlint.com/ & peste your settings files json text & validate.